# Using the wrong Localizable.string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have an iOS app with a default language (English).
It also has a French localization and works as expected in both languages.

Here is the problem I am having:
When setting the device to a language other than English(default) or a language for which localization is provided (for example setting the device to Japanese); the app does not fall as expected in the default language. But it keeps the last language used for the app.
Why is that? And how can I fix it?

I have found a few post with a similar issue, but the solutions proposed did not work for me. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485048/iphone-wrong-localizable-strings-used), where the problem is similar to mine.

I am using Xcode version 11.1 and iOS version 12.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

iOS will have a list of preferred language order based on the previously selected languages.

So, if you changed from English then to an unmapped language (e.g ko), the application will have as AppleLanguages the array:

> [ko-(ZoneCode), en-(ZoneCode)].

You can avoid this procedure using this code below:

```
let defaultCultureCode: String = "en"
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let currentAppleLanguages = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
if let currentLanguages = currentAppleLanguages {
    if(!currentLanguages.isEmpty && !(currentLanguages.first?.contains(["en", "fr"]))!) {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            defaults.set([defaultCultureCode], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
```

I used this string extension to check if the current languages contain the available language:

```
extension String {
    public func contains(_ elements: [String]) -> Bool {
        var haveElementOnString = false

        if elements.count == 0 { return false }
        else { elements.forEach{ element in haveElementOnString = haveElementOnString || self.contains(element)} }

        return haveElementOnString
    }
}
```

The next step it's up to you to define the best strategy.

In my application context, it will always be defined as English by default because it is the only .strings file available. All the other supported strings will be downloaded and then a message will be displayed to the user warning that new languages are available and will be applied next time.

There's a lot of information on StackOverflow about bundle.localizedStringForKey or NSLocalizedString that could help you to found the best solution for what you need.

Also, this is only the validation and update for the current locale and the default language. this doesn't include the Region section (e.g. ko-KR (KR)).

I found an interesting text on this topic that could be useful 
[How not to do localization](https://blog.cocoafrog.de/localization/programming/how-not-to/2017/07/28/how-not-to-do-localization.html).

I hope it solves your problem!

Comment: This is very useful information, it makes things much clearer. But where do you include your code. I tried it, somewhere in viewDidLoad. It does not work the first time I launch the app, it works only from the second time and after. Do you know why?

Comment: I also tried to place the code inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but the result was identical.

Comment: Same with the code inside application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: It will only reflect on application if you're not using NSLocalizedString. I suggest use the bundle.localizedStringForKey implementation. I will update my response will the full solution

Comment: Yes. After digging a bit more in the subject, I see that for one same user there can be several preferred languages according to her/his previous settings.